# Simple ViewPager Application causing memory leak error

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-viewpager

I try to made a example simple ViewPager app but Ive got error. I thought it was the image resolution fault but after changing ImageView as TextView and writing example text on it Ive got the same error. (after commented the ViewPAger implementation works fine)

> channel '2d5df67 com.example.k.myapplication/com.example.k.myapplication.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<String> list;
ViewPager viewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


  list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
    list.add("http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2016/03/ultraviolet_image_shows_the_sun_s_intricate_atmosphere/15891756-1-eng-GB/Ultraviolet_image_shows_the_Sun_s_intricate_atmosphere_node_full_image_2.jpg");
    list.add("http://pnge.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/1488980395_548_image.jpg");
    list.add("http://pnge.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/image.png");
    list.add("https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
    list.add("http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2016/03/ultraviolet_image_shows_the_sun_s_intricate_atmosphere/15891756-1-eng-GB/Ultraviolet_image_shows_the_Sun_s_intricate_atmosphere_node_full_image_2.jpg");
    list.add("http://pnge.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/1488980395_548_image.jpg");
    list.add("http://pnge.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/image.png");
    viewPager  = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPAger);
    ViewPAgerAdapter adapter = new ViewPAgerAdapter(MainActivity.this,list);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class ViewPAgerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<String> record;
    private Context context;
   private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ViewPAgerAdapter(Context context, List<String>record) {
        this.record=record;
        this.context=context;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,container);

        ImageView img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
      Glide.with(context).load(record.get(position)).fitCenter().into(img);

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return record.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

**Item layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity layout**

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.k.myapplication.MainActivity">


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPAger"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you try fresco

Comment: its not the image library fault. I try to replace My ImageView with simple TextView with page counting and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your manifest -- android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|mcc|mnc"